# Função que procura um nó que satisfaz um callback

Tags: javascript, estrutura-de-dados

Encontrei uma implementação de listas ligadas em javascript e vi esse método que retorna o primeiro nó que satisfaz a condição do callback e não entendi muito bem o primeiro if, entendi que ele verifica se callback é uma função só não entendi muito bem isso "Object.prototype.toString.call(callback)", isso chama um método toString usando o this que o callback está associado ? Se não for entendi errado.

Link se for necessário entender o contexto: [Implementing a Linked List in JavaScript](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/implementing-a-linked-list-in-javascript-3f71c83487b5)

```
find(callback){
        if(Object.prototype.toString.call(callback) !== '[object Function]'){
            return new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
        };

        if(!this.head) return false;

        let currentNode = this.head;

        while(currentNode){
            if(callback && callback(currentNode.value)) {
                return currentNode;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        };

        return undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse primeiro `if`, como disseste, é uma salvaguarda para só correr o resto do código se `callback` for uma função.

Usar `Object.prototype.toString.call(algo)` é comum para descobrir o tipo de alguma coisa que passamos a esse `.call(`. Isto é uma maneira de corrigir uma lacuna na linguagem que é não haver métodos nativos para todos os Tipos. Contudo este método não é ele próprio fiável a 100% pois o método `.toString` pode ser sobrescrito e retornar valores que quebram este código.
Os resultados possíveis de `Object.prototype.toString.call(algo)` são:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call([]); // [object Array]
Object.prototype.toString.call({}); // [object Object]
Object.prototype.toString.call(''); // [object String]
Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date()); // [object Date]
Object.prototype.toString.call(1); // [object Number]
Object.prototype.toString.call(function () {}); // [object Function]
Object.prototype.toString.call(/test/i); // [object RegExp]
Object.prototype.toString.call(true); // [object Boolean]
Object.prototype.toString.call(null); // [object Null]
Object.prototype.toString.call(); // [object Undefined]
```

**Porém**, neste caso, não há razão para não usar simplesmente

```
if(typeof callback !== 'function'){
```

... é mais simples e semanticamente correto.